# How to Get OAuth Token From GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, oauth, google-sheets-api, google-drive-android-api

I am trying to build an Android application that created a spreadsheet in Google Drive and then adds some data to it. I can successfuly create the spreadsheet using the Google Drive Android API which involves creating a `GoogleApiClient` and using a class that implements `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`.

When I start the application I make a new `GoogleApiClient` and am prompted to select an account. In the `onConnected` callback I can new pass my `GoogleApiClient` to `Drive.DriveApi` to query and create files and folders.

However, to add data to a Google sheet I need to use the GoogleSheets API. This does not have an Android API as far as I can tell but it does have a gdata API. In order to use it however I need an OAuth token.

Is there anyway I can get an OAuth token from the `GoogleApiClient` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can just use

```
    GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
String[] SCOPES = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"};

     mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                    .setSelectedAccountName(ACC_NAME);

        GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mCredential.getSelectedAccountName(),SCOPE)
```

[GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: What is `mCredential`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil#getToken(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

call this method in an AsyncTask as it performs a network operation.

Comment: How do I get the account object from the `GoogleApiClient`?