# How to download google drive selected file in android programmatically?

Tags: android, download, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Google drive selection code is below :

```
private void initializeGoogleDrive() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)
            .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[]{"text/plain", "text/html"})
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);
    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Utility.appLog(TAG, "Unable to send intent");
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_OPENER) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
        String resourceId = driveId.getResourceId();
        String downloadUrl = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + resourceId + "&export=download";
        Utility.appLog(TAG, "Download Url :: " + downloadUrl);
    } 
}
}
```

we can get download url but unfortunately download can not be done because of authentication error occurred when i am trying to download file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use asyc task with httpurlconnection setrequst with auth key

Comment: I tried but authentication error occurred, can you please send me full code for download google drive file?

Comment: you need to pass authtoken when you are requesting the url...do you want example??

Comment: yes. please.if possible then please put sample in any blogs and give me share link. OR send me example link

Comment: check out the answer

Answer (score 1):

Do this in Asynctask

```
try{
       URL url = new URL(URL);
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mCredential.getSelectedAccountName(), Constants.SCOPE));
       conn.setDoInput(true);
       // Starts the query
       conn.connect();
       int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        //you will recive the file in input stream
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.ext");

            FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = conn.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;

            while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutput.close();
      }
```

I'm using dependencies,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
```

Comment: Please explain : mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() and mCredential.getSelectedAccountName() and how can i get from my above code?

Comment: The name of the selected account check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098468/how-to-get-oauth-token-from-googleapiclient/35098661#35098661

Comment: I seen your link: In this link use GoogleAccountCredential and ExponentialBackOff class. any dependency use for this both class?

Comment: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'

Comment: yes you are right. Only 2 things that's i don't know : android 'ACC_NAME' and 'scope'.

Comment: look at that link i have mentioned scope and acc_name will be selected account email id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102358/discussion-between-patel-and-madhur).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for downloading the drive file

```
private val mExecutor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
```

You need to specify the path to store the downloaded file and ID of the file you want to download.
Here is the method to download file

```
 fun downloadFile(targetFile: java.io.File?, fileId: String?): Task<Void?>? {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, {
            val outputStream: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(targetFile)
            mDriveService.files([fileId].executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream)
            null
        })
    }
```

Comment: There's an alternative approach we can use (if using Kotlin already): https://nickskelton.medium.com/converting-firebase-api-callbacks-to-kotlin-flows-3eea87429ee9